# Sorting a Ruby array

Tags: ruby, sorting

I am trying to sort large inputs in the fastest way in ascending order. The code is something like this:

```
t=gets
ti=t.to_i
r=[]
for i in(0..ti)
    k=gets
    r[i]=k.to_i
end
r.sort_by{|x| -x.last}
```

This is giving me an error saying `undefined method 'last' for nil:nilclass <nomethoderror>
from tsort.rb: in sort_by
from tsort.rb in 'each'
from tsort.rb in 'sort_by'`

I don't know where am I wrong.

That's what I have tried for sorting an array...which is `r[]` which has all the numbers in `t`! Can anyone please help.

My inputs are less than 10^6!

Comment: Try to give you're variable names more meaning. Its a bit difficult to read.

Comment: Apparently some of your Array elements are nil. That is strange, because you explicitly call to_i on all arguments. Even nil.to_i is 0. Can you let us know which input you are supplying? Is this exactly identical to your production code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't reproduce your exact error, I get `undefined method 'last' for n:Fixnum (NoMethodError)`. That makes sense, because you're calling the `last` method on `x`, which will hold the values of your `Array` `r`, all `Fixnums`, which do not have a `last` method.

It should work if you replace the last line with:

```
r.sort
```

The `sort` method will sort your `Array` in ascending order by default.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sort a list of integers taken from STDIN I suggest something like the following:

```
lines = STDIN.readlines.map { |x| x.strip.to_i }.sort
puts lines.join(', ')
```

It's cleaner, more *rubyish* and faster (read the documentation for [`Enumerable.sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003151) to see why `sort` is a better alternative to `sort_by`).

I also see your code expects a number that says how many lines to read. You can get the same behavior by modifying the example above as follows:

```
line_count = gets.strip.to_i
lines = (1..line_count).collect { gets.strip.to_i }.sort
puts lines.join(', ')
```

Comment: i want to sort a particular quantity of numbers , that i will take as input so how to do t using 
lines = STDIN.readlines.map { |x| x.strip.to_i }.sort
puts lines.join(', ')

Comment: @mekasperasky: I've edited my answer to reflect your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try the sort function on [Array's](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002208) think it does what you need.